# Wordpress is showing /index1.php/ in the URL

Tags: php, wordpress

a client just mailed me and asked that suddenly the /index1.php/ does appear in the URL, which shouldn't be the case. It's about these pages https://www.stern-verkehr.at/index1.php/bahn/ and
https://www.stern-verkehr.at/index1.php/bus/

The client said that they didn't do anything with the website, and the content in the backend stayed the same.

Also some contents didn't showed up, until I updated the theme.

I sadly am not a programmer, only a designer and our programmer is not in the house right now. Would it help if I do update of Wordpress to the newst version?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change permalink and save it once again maybe it's permalink issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NUHX.jpg).

Comment: Hello and welcome. I suggest you avoid answering  questions with such few useful information. At that point you're just guessing and we'd prefer actual answers, not guesses.

Comment: Hi, sadly it didn't help. It wasn't the permalink.

Comment: Then it's a problem with your .htaccess file please look into it.
For more information please suggest this link https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like wordpress permalink issue. you can go to Dashboard Settings -> Permalinks and select the Post Name on Radio Button and Save changes. It should help.
Thanks